# Source Maps are off using ng serve, correct in ng serve --prod

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli

I have an application built using Angular2. When running using `ng serve`, my source maps are all off and I cannot debug (using Chrome Dev Tools). If I set breakpoints it will often stop at random points, so I am assuming it is a problem with the mapping

However when I use `ng serve --prod`, the mapping seems to work fine.

Wondering if anyone else has run into this issue?

Comment: what is your Angular-Cli version ?

Comment: I have been having some of the same issues, it sort of comes and goes. Tho closed, the following was raised with the ng2 team here: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/2926#event-848126165

Comment: I should add that I have had the best luck with "npm uninstall -g angular-cli", "npm cache clear", "npm install angular-cli@latest, "ng new proj-name,"  then copying contents of the "src" folder of the old project to the new one.  Sort of a clean start.

Comment: Yep thats it! It was due to an old version of Angular-cli. Have updated with uninstall/install and now it is working. Thanks guys!